# How to automatically browse on the current date within a large dataset

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, large-data

I have created a large dataset that contains the dates of the year (1 cell for 1 date) in Excel. The dates are placed in rows. Each date contains the schedule for the respective day.

When opening the sheet, I want to go/browse directly to today's date. Do you know how this can be done?

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim CellToShow AS Range
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
x = Day(Date)
Set CellToShow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues)
If CellToShow Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "No Cell for day " & x & " found.", vbCritical
Else
  With CellToShow
   .Select
   .Show 'Scroll the window to show the cell
  End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do a sort on opening: most recent at top? Or have a space at the top with the latest using now().

Comment: You can use `SORT()` function like `=SORT(A2:A50000,1,-1)`.

Comment: @SolarMike, I do not want today's date to be on top. I want to be transferred to today's date across the columns. Since my dates are placed across the row 2, I want to be transferred to the respective column with the today's date (i.e. column BR) - but is not necessary for me to be transferred to column, it would be a good fit if jumped to the cell containing the today's date.

Comment: So what have you considered? we gave some good suggestions that you have trashed.

Comment: I have used this VBA code but it directs me to the first cell containing a date not the today's date- Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim CellToShow AS Range
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    x = Day(Date)
    Set CellToShow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If CellToShow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Cell for day " & x & " found.", vbCritical
    Else
        With CellToShow
            .Select
            .Show 'Scroll the window to show the cell
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Comment: `x = Day(Date)` will store in x only the day of today's date. Try `x = Date`